# Parsing/handling big files in PHP on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

Is it possible to handle/parse big files via PHP on Heroku?
I need to download a zip file, unzip it and then parse the resulting 85GB XML file.

Im not sure how to do this on Heroku. They dont let you storage files that big.

Any ideas? Only reference I can find is the AWS S3 wrapper that you can upload files to.

Comment: Have you looked into streaming the zip file? You're working with some pretty large data here, maybe have a look at a library like: https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP

Comment: @Bossman that library only seem to stream the files into a zip... I dont need to create a zip file. The file already exists but I need to download it, unzip it and then parse the content.

Comment: Sorry you're right. PHP has native zip support, maybe you could look at and experiment with https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstream.php and  https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getfromname.php